# Collision Detection in Direction (SFML)

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I am experiencing a problem with collision detection, an efficiency problem. Right now I want to make it so that my player square stops traveling in the direction of collision into the static object. I followed what a guy did in a tutorial when he checked this type of collision but it's long and hard to understand let alone read. Is there an easier way to tackle this issue?

```
sf::RectangleShape player;
player.setSize(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
player.setPosition(width / 2, height / 2);

sf::RectangleShape object;
object.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
object.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
object.setPosition((width / 2) - 200, (height / 2) - 120);

sf::Vector2f velocity(0, 0);
float gravity = .1;

bool jumping = true;

sf::Event event;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
            {
                if (jumping == false)
                {
                    velocity.y = -3.5;
                    jumping = true;
                }
            }
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
            {
                velocity.x = 3;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
            {
                velocity.x = -3;
            }
        }
    }

    //Move the player
    player.move(velocity);

    //Gravity

    if (player.getPosition().y < height / 2)
    {
        velocity.y += gravity;
    }
    else if (player.getPosition().y >= height / 2)
    {
        player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, height / 2);
        jumping = false;
    }

    //Check collision with object
    sf::FloatRect player_boundingBox = player.getGlobalBounds();

    if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().y + 50 < object.getPosition().y + 5 && player.getPosition().y + 50 > object.getPosition().y && player.getPosition().y < object.getPosition().y)
    {
        player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, object.getPosition().y - 50);
    }
    else if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().x > object.getPosition().x + 90 && player.getPosition().x < object.getPosition().x + 99)
    {
        player.setPosition(object.getPosition().x + 100, player.getPosition().y);
        velocity.x = 0;
    }
    else if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().x + 50 < object.getPosition().x + 10 && player.getPosition().x + 50 > object.getPosition().x)
    {
        player.setPosition(object.getPosition().x - 50, player.getPosition().y);
        velocity.x = 0;
    }
    else if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().y > object.getPosition().y + 97 && player.getPosition().y < object.getPosition().y + 99)
    {
        player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, object.getPosition().y + 100);
        velocity.y = 0;
    }

    window.clear(sf::Color::White); //Clear

    window.draw(player);
    window.draw(object);

    window.display(); //Display
}
```

Comment: If you have trouble after following a tutorial and asking about it here, it's a good idea to add a link to the tutorial, this may help you get better answers.

Comment: Also, you mentioned "an efficiency problem", yet I see nothing else about efficiency in the question. Could you review the question and make sure that the issue that you have is there, along with what you expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are checking for intersection in every `if` and `else if`. So you are asking the same question four times in worst case. I recommend to make this

```
if (player_bounds.intersect(object_bounds))
{
    //Other conditions
}
```

For the rest of the condition. Depending on your game, you should be able to precalculate as possible as you can before you reach the `if`s.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

So for starters the only part of the code that is collision detecting is:

```
//Check collision with object
sf::FloatRect player_boundingBox = player.getGlobalBounds();

if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().y + 50 < object.getPosition().y + 5 && player.getPosition().y + 50 > object.getPosition().y && player.getPosition().y < object.getPosition().y)
{
    player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, object.getPosition().y - 50);
}
else if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().x > object.getPosition().x + 90 && player.getPosition().x < object.getPosition().x + 99)
{
    player.setPosition(object.getPosition().x + 100, player.getPosition().y);
    velocity.x = 0;
}
else if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().x + 50 < object.getPosition().x + 10 && player.getPosition().x + 50 > object.getPosition().x)
{
    player.setPosition(object.getPosition().x - 50, player.getPosition().y);
    velocity.x = 0;
}
else if (player_boundingBox.intersects(object.getGlobalBounds()) && player.getPosition().y > object.getPosition().y + 97 && player.getPosition().y < object.getPosition().y + 99)
{
    player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, object.getPosition().y + 100);
    velocity.y = 0;
}
```

What its doing is check if the players "box" aka bounds (The area around the player that you want to collide with something else) is intersecting with another objects "box". In this case the object is a rectangle defined at the top:

```
sf::RectangleShape object;
```

If the players "box" is past the objects "box" it pushes places the player back.